# Cannot establish a communication between two nRF24L01+ modules

Tags: nrf24l01

I’m willing to experiment with nRF24L01+, so I have bought a set of modules from China, and I’m trying to establish a communication between an Arduino Nano and a Raspberry Pi 3.

At first, I tried to write my own sending program (in C++) for the Arduino and my own receiving program (in Python) for the Raspberry Pi, but I could not receive anything.

I thought it might be a problem with some missing initialization, so I decided to try using [a dedicated library](https://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/). I tried the example `scanner` programs, and it seems to work fine on both the Arduino and the Raspberry Pi sides: it detects some activity that corresponds to my WiFi network. So I tried the `pingpair_dyn` examples. The sender side appears to send data, but the receiver does not see anything and the sender times out. I tried both directions with the same result.

I read that there might be some issues with the 3.3V pin of the Arduino Nano that may be insufficiently stable to power the nRF24L01+ chip, so I tried to power it from the 5V pin, through a L33CZ LDO regulator, and with decoupling capacitors, with no success.

I thought it might be a cabling issue, so I double- and triple-checked. The chip respond as expected, so I think the SPI signals (`MOSI`, `MISO`, `CSN`) are correctly connected. And since the `scanner` also works, I think the `CE` signal is fine as well.

I thought it might be a problem with my WiFi network interfering: even if I took care to choose a channel away from the WiFi channel, the antennas of the WiFi AP and of my laptop were close the the nRF24L01+ modules, and I thought that might result in a low gain of the LNA. So I trieed shutting down my WiFi (both the AP and my laptop’s), and I still could not establish a communication.

My first tests were with a few meters and a wall between the modules, but I also tried with only a few centimeters, and I still could not get any successful communication…

Any idea what I may be doing wrong? Is there a chance I bought some counterfeit nRF24L01+ chips or bad modules?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the datasheet for the modules?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I can’t. I bought [those modules](https://www.dx.com/p/nrf24l01-2-4ghz-enhanced-wireless-modules-black-4-pcs-2057721) from DealExtreme and they don’t provide datasheets.

Comment: If the modules are undocumented then the best thing might be to discard them and purchase new ones from a reliable source.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson You may be right, but it sounds like a rather extreme solution, given that it won’t be used for a professionally, electronics is just a hobby for me. Moreover, the module is very simple (only a few passive components besides the nRF24L01+ chip) and looks much like Nordic Semiconductor’s reference design. And it looks like **many** people use such modules with good results, so I hoped someone may have had the same problem as mine.